# Finding the dimensions of a Hypercube by the number of its edges

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

> What is the dimension of a hypercube with 524,288 edges?

I know that for $Q_n$, the number of edges is $(\frac{1}{2})n2^n = n2^{n-1}$. So I wrote this down in my book: 
$$(\frac{1}{2})n2^n = n2^{n-1} = 524288$$

My question is how do you solve for n? Do I multiply 524288 by 2 then solve for n? Like this:
 $$n2^n = 1048576$$
Or is it just a big guessing game of trial and error when you solve for n?

Comment: taking log to base 2, $n \approx \log_2 1048576$ and must be sligthly smaller.

Comment: But there is also that n in front of $2^n$ so $n \neq \log_2 1048576$. It is more like $n \approx \log_2 \frac{1048576}{n}$. It's better to assume that $n \le \log_2 1048576$

Comment: It would be fairly easy to express $524288$ as a power of $2$ times $n$.

Comment: @hardmath And how would you do that?

Comment: Unless you’re familiar with the _product log function_, it’s probably gonna be a guessing game. The good news is that you won’t have to run through too many numbers. Hint: It’s an even integer between 10 and 20.

Comment: Since $524288 = 2^{19} = n 2^{n-1}$, $n$ must itself be a power of two.  There are very few powers of two between (say) $10$ and $20$.

Comment: What about a hypercube that has 4980736 edges?

Comment: If we factor $4980736 = 19\cdot 2^{18}$ then it becomes obvious what $n$ must be to match $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$.  While prime factorization may not be an easy task in general, here we are only required to pull out all the factors of two (in the given number of edges), and the problem is then reduced to solution almost by inspection.

Answer (score 5):

$1048576=2^{20 }=n2^n $

So let $n=2^a $ and $2^a2^{2^a}=2^{a+2^a}=2^{20} $

$a+2^a=20$

As $2^a>a$ then $2^a $ must be the leading power of $2$ in the binary representation of $20$ and it must be such that $a $ is what's left.

$20=16 +4$ so if this hyper cube is actually possible, it must be that $16=2^4$.  Which it does.

So $n=2^a=16$.

So $a=4$ and $n=16$.

Comment: Thanks, your edited answer is much easier to understand

Comment: $a =\log_2 n $.  So $\log_2 n + \log_2 2^{n}=a+n=a+2^n=20$.

Comment: OH, never really thought of that way.

Comment: One more question, if the answer is odd then is it just a guessing game? Say like a hypercube has 4980736 edges? The answer is odd by the way

Comment: $n2^n = 2*4980736 = 2^{19}*19$ so the answer to that is obvious.... You are going to get $n2^n= k*2^m$ so you'll have to have $n = k*2^a$ and $2^{m-a} = 2^n$ or $m-a = n$.  Solving for $n$ will be a guessing game but crimeny!  $n= k*2^a = m-a$ when $k$ and $m$ are known is a *huge* restriction.  It should be immediately obvious and *easy* to solve.

Comment: If the cube has $K$ edges then you have $n2^n = 2K$.  If you find the prime factorization of $K$ you will get $n2^n = j*2^m$ where $j$ is odd.  Then means $n = j*2^a$ and $2^n = 2^{m-a}$ and $n= m-a$.  Solvin $n=j*2^a = m-a$.  Just $a = 1,2,...$ it won't take long.

Comment: A better example:  $K= 24576=3*2^{13}$.  so $n2^n = 3*2^{14}$.  So $n = 3*2^a$ and $2^n = 2^{14 - a}$ so $n = 3*2^a = 14 - a$.  Well... trial and error but ... c'mon!!!!  $a = 1; n=3*2 = 14-1$ Nope;  and $a=2$ then $n = 3*4= 14 -2$ yep.  So $n= 12$.

Comment: ok thank you so much